# Rotating a 300 000 km long rod

Tags: photons, relativity

A 300 000 km long rod is rotated (around its axis) from one end A. At this very instant a photon is emitted from A in direction of B the other end of the rod. Will the other end of the rod B have rotated before the photon reaches it?

Comment: Well, given that photons don't cross distances instantaneously, and that the rod is already rotating, obviously the photon doesn't reach B. Now, if the photon is emitted at the same time rotation starts, then it obviously does reach B. The length of the rod and the rigidity of the material are immaterial

Comment: What is the refractive index of the rod, compared to the elastic properties of the material it's made of?

Comment: Is the photon traveling in a transparent rod, or is it traveling in vacuum outside of the rod?

Comment: Sorry Garyp. The photon  travels alongside the rod and  in vacuum. I read Nasu's answer.  I believe it is the right answer. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Logically it cannot, if you treat the outer end of the rod as a semi circle (which should be the path it traces), and the path of the photon as the diameter (which it should be), then the diameter is shorter than the circumference, and seeing as nothing can out-pace a photon, the photon **HAS** to arrive first

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by "is rotated from one end" you mean you push the end with a tangential force, to start the rotation. This push that you give to the end of the rod will initiate a transverse mechanical wave in the rod. The speed of these waves in common solids is less than 5000 m/s. So assuming there is no damping in the rod, the other end will "hear" about this push after at least 60,000 s or about 17 hours. The light will travel the same distance in 1 s.